# Where to "post preprocessor"?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a project of C lib binding, which uses C2HS. Now I want to make some wrappers. Instead of manually writing them, I'd like to generate them by Cabal custom-setup.

The problem is that, I could not figure out a place to do it.

If there was no preprocessor, I could fake my generator as a preprocessor and use existing mechanism of Cabal (hookedPreProcessors) to do the task.

But since there is a preprocessor, the task must be done against the buildDir of LocalBuildInfo. And preprocessor is called deeply in buildHook.

So to sum up, is there a place in Cabal setup process that I could insert a task before ghc compilation and after other proprocessors?

Comment: Is the generated code Haskell? Then you might try Template Haskell. Or you could take inspiration on how Amazonka does it.

Comment: I am not sure Template Haskell works for me. I need to use the result of another preprocessor. Thanks for the Amazonka suggestion. Let me see what it does.